# What operations do the GPS recievers perform after capturing signal from Satellite?

Tags: gps

What are the operations on the signals recieved by a GPS reciever ? 
How does it process them towards achieving a position fix ?

I need explanation with the decoding and correlating part of the signal. How does it determine the position of a satellite when the signal it is recieving from many satellite is mixed up with the signals from other satellites in the wireless medium .

I'd be glad if you point me to a good article/link that explains this well.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to lern about GPS signals I recommend you to look on this website http://www.kowoma.de/en/gps/signals.htm generally this site is very useful if you are clueless in GPS subject